# non-mapped field in DataContract not supported

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm adding a Status property to a class that is based on the ExpirationDate.

ExpirationDate is in the database while Status is calculated in the class.

This runs but throws an exception because the field is not in the table.

```
    [DataMember]
    public ClientStatus Status {
        get; set;
    }
```

But everything else throws NotSupported and doesn't even hit the database.

```
    [NotMapped] or [IgnoreDataMember]
    public ClientStatus Status {
        get {
          //  return GetStatus();
          return ClientStatus.Active;
        }
        set { }  // tried with and without
    }
```

Execution here:

```
 return query.Skip(startRow).Take(pageSize).ToArray();
```

query.Sql = '((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery)q1).Sql' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Internal exception is

```
Message = "The specified type member 'Status' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."
```

That would make sense in the case where I'm trying to read it from the database, but that *doesn't* get the exception. It is only when not mapped that it throws NotSupported.

Comment: Did you try using that property in the query? That exception would expected in this case. That error is thrown when you try something that *isn't* mapped in a query. How is EF supposed to guess how to translate this into SQL? Post the *actual* query, whatever is assigned to the `query` variable.

Comment: If `Status` is hard-coded to `Active` though, why use it in *any* query?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Status is hard-coded to Active to prove that the exception isn't coming from GetStatus and that it isn't caused by GetStatus being a private member of the class. Also, I'm trying NOT to use it in the query. That's the point.

Comment: If I use [DataMember] then it is requested by the query in the SELECT column list and looks normal. I'll add that to the question. If I use [NotMapped] then query.SQL shows an error in the debugger and I don't get any SQL, valid or otherwise.

Comment: EF isn't supposed to guess. It is supposed to not map (include) the member in the query at all.

Comment: EF is supposed to throw when it can't translate the query to SQL. Post enough code to reproduce the issue. Somehow, somewhere, you are using this field. Right now only you know *what* that query does. Other people would have to try various combinations until they get the same exception